# React Hello World issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm completly new with react and currently testing this tutorial http://jmfurlott.com/tutorial-setting-up-a-single-page-react-web-app-with-react-router-and-webpack/

When I try to start the application I get the following error message:

[image: stacktrace]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial on that site is now out of date, as Babel 6 no longer natively supports React.  You need to include a plugin and configure webpack as appropriate.

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/

Install the plugin:

```
$ npm install babel-preset-react
```

You'll need to then configure your loader in webpack to use the plugin.

This blog will show you how to use webpack with babel6:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html